# F/OSS for the PIC24?

Tags: embedded, pic

I'm learning embedded programming with the PIC24, and I'm looking for something "real-world" to dig into to help me learn. Are there any free software projects that might be targeting to the PIC? Anything that I could help port, or a niche I could try to fill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for software projects, look up gputils - is the open source assembler and linker, and sdcc - an open source c/c++ compiler (lacks a PIC24 port).

If you are looking for embedded projects, there is nothing specific that comes to mind. However, do visit the piclist to pick up code snippets and learn from examples. Some of the best PIC coders contribute there.

If you are looking for hardware projects, there are verilog PIC16/18 cores on opencores but no PIC24 cores yet.

So, there's plenty to suit all tastes.

Answer (score 2):

Quite old (2005) but may help you to start:

http://www.gnupic.org/

For example, gpsim at http://www.dattalo.com/gnupic/gpsim.html